# Python 3.4, Pygame - I want to create a grid to be able to place sprites in differently

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

Since I am new in python I do not know how to create certain things, I am using pygame and I want to create a grid to interact with a grid like in this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX3Xa.jpg). I am using python 3.4.3 and pygame. I would like some help figuring out how to create a program to interact with that grid to use to have sprites be added to it and removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the sprites manually.

First, add them to a group:

```
group = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

This is very useful for drawing a collection of sprites.

Second, use a nested for loop to create the sprites:

```
width, height = 10, 10  # 10 rows and 10 cols
sprite_size = 15  # size of one sprite
for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        pos_x, pos_y = col * sprite_size, row * sprite_size

        # create your sprite at position pos_x and pos_y
        # add creation code of your sprite here

        group.add(sprite)  # add sprite to group
```

To remove a sprite from the group, you can use

```
group.remove(sprite)
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being specific enough, I dont know if its already in this code, sorry if I'm just clueless on how certain parts of python work but, I want it to do it where if I have a sprite in the 1st slot in the picture that it'll be placed in the 2nd slot and vise versa if you understand what I mean now.

Comment: Not really .. Do you want to order a collection of sprites using a grid?

Comment: Yeah, like I would like order a collection of sprites using a grid, because this is for an inventory system